# How do I prove combinatorically that $\binom{r}{r}+\binom{r+1}{r}+...+\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

I tried counting subsets with r+1 elements from the set {1,2,....n, n+1} which gives RHS.
However I could not come up with an answer corresponding to LHS.

$$\binom{r}{r}+\binom{r+1}{r}+...+\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1} $$

Comment: Hint: consider the lexicographically largest of the things you wind up choosing from $n+1$. Where can it be, and how many ways are there to choose the rest of the things?

Comment: There are multiple proofs of several kinds at the link; the one by **hunter** some distance down is combinatorial and very clearly presented.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for your answer. Had I known the duplicate answer, I would not have asked the question. I am new here, so should I delete this question?

Comment: @AlexParker: You’re welcome. It’s entirely up to you; someone who happens to stumble on this question gets a pointer to lots of answers, which is nice, but apart from that nothing is lost if you do delete it.